# Protobuf-net memcache provider null type error on deserialize

Tags: .net, memcached, protobuf-net

I'm using lastest protobuf-net lib with protobuf-net memcache provider. I need to serialize list of custom type MyClass

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public int a {get; set;}
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public int b {get; set;}
}
```

So I need to store/retreive:

```
List<MyClass> myList
```

When values are stored through protobuf and then retreived from cache all goes well. But if value is stored in memcache (in correct protobuf format) i.e. from another thread/app and after that that value is retreived from cache deserialization fails due to NullReferenceExceptions of type field.

So when set goes first, type of serialized value is stored in typeCache variable and then retreived from that dictionary. But if value is present in memcache but not set in current thread typeCache var doesn't contain that type and throws NullReference on deserialization.

Are there any ways to fix this or some workaround?

Deeper investigations:
Serialization/deserialization process for enyim implemented in `ProtoTranscoder.cs`. It contains `NetTranscoder` class that has `Dictionary<ArraySegment<byte>, Type> typeCache`.
So when set goes first serialized type (i.e. `List<MyClass>`) is stored in `typeCache` var and all goes well. If value is present in memcache, but not set in current app/thread on deserialize it retreived by this code:

```
type = Type.GetType(enc.GetString(buffer, keyOffset, len));
byte[] standaloneBuffer = new byte[len];
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, keyOffset, standaloneBuffer, 0, len);
key = new ArraySegment<byte>(standaloneBuffer, 0, len);
sync.EnterWriteLock();
try
   {
        // did somebody beat us to it?
        Type tmp;
        if (typeCache.TryGetValue(key, out tmp)) return tmp;
        typeCache.Add(key, type);
        return type;   <-- Here it returns null, if type not present in typeCache
   }
finally
   {
        sync.ExitWriteLock();
   }
```

To reproduce that error:

1. List item
2. Create and store some List in memcache (with configured prototranscoder)
3. Restart current app (or start another thread)
4. Try to get value by key from memcache from those "another thread"

Here is stack trace of this error:
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type]

```
   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.PrepareDeserialize(Object value, Type& type) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:592
   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:577
   ProtoBuf.Caching.Enyim.NetTranscoder.Enyim.Caching.Memcached.ITranscoder.Deserialize(CacheItem item) in c:\Users\akureniov\work\protobuf-net-1\protobuf-net.Enyim\protobuf-net.Enyim\ProtoTranscoder.cs:109
   Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient.PerformTryGet(String key, UInt64& cas, Object& value) +179
   Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient.TryGet(String key, Object& value) +42
   Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient.Get(String key) +15
```

Comment: Please be specific: which dll versions are you using? The "latest protobuf-net lib" doesn't include the enyim transcoder (the "Extensions" project hasn't been revised for v2, and does not build AFAIK, although it is on my list to look at). So: are you using an older version of the transcoder? have you patched "Extensions"? or are you storing the types manually?

Comment: Are you using the `ProtoTranscoder` NuGet package by any chance?

Comment: I'm using protobuf-net-r622 lib and protobuf enyim module compiled from source from svn (it goes in svn as separate project). Nuget package don't works with couchbase enyim.cache lib witch has different publick key.

Comment: can you point me *exactly* at which "protobuf enyim module" you are using / compiling from source? it is hard to comment without that...

Comment: It's located in your svn. Folder called "protobuf-net.Enyim". I've updated reference protobuf-net library to version r622 and then compiled it. Also I'll update my first post with deeper trace of error soon.

Comment: d'oh! face-palm; I completely missed that one! Stupid memory by me... looking

Comment: k; I've tried to add a repro test against my local memcached server, and I can't get it to error. All the access to `typeCache` looks correctly synchronized, so I don't think it is necessarily a threading issue. However, it could be something to do with not successfully resolving the type. Do you happen to have a stack-trace, or anything I can use to reliably reproduce the error?

Comment: May be it's not syncronization issue. Error appears if I restart my app (restarting app pool). Values are present in memcache, but `typeCache` variable after restart is empty. So when it tries to get something from it, it returns null. It's web application so it can be launched on sevral IIS servers and on one server value is stored, and on another it should be retreived.

Comment: K; Can you please add `, true` at the end of line 78 in `ProtoTranscoder.cs`, and see what it says next time it errors? I *suspect* it relates to assembly loading... so that line becomes: `type = Type.GetType(enc.GetString(buffer, keyOffset, len), true);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24499/discussion-between-alex-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) we found "bug" in type trimming in ProtoTranscoder.cs: NetTranscoder: void WriteType(MemoryStream ms, Type type). This code block cause error, because it cuts too much:

```
int i = typeName.IndexOf(','); // first split
if (i >= 0) { i = typeName.IndexOf(',', i + 1); } // second split
if (i >= 0) { typeName = typeName.Substring(0, i); } // extract type/assembly only
```

It worked well for simple types, but fails on List, Dictionary, etc.

To avoid this it's better to use regexp to cut not nessesary info (like culture, publickkeytoken, etc). So here is a replacement (need to replace above rows with this), quiet rude, but working in most cases:

```
typeName = Regex.Replace(typeName, @", Version=\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+", string.Empty);
typeName = Regex.Replace(typeName, @", Culture=\w+", string.Empty);
typeName = Regex.Replace(typeName, @", PublicKeyToken=\w+", string.Empty);
```

This regexp doesn't cut type's assembly, which is needed for custom types. But for standart types it's `mscorlib` and it can be deleted safely in most cases by adding another line:

```
typeName = Regex.Replace(typeName, @", mscorlib", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Last paragraph should say "assembly", not "namespace" - but looks good, thanks! I'll see about merging it later. Much appreciated.

Comment: Fixed last paragraph. Thanks. Also I've tested my code on complex Lists and Dictionaries, seems it works well. Removing mscorlib also works fine.

Comment: Did this ever get fixed?  I think I'm seeing this issue with protobuf-net v2.0.0.621.  It's weird too -- I can successfully store some Lists but not others.  It appears to be dependent on the generic type of the List.

Comment: As I can see archive on off. site hasn't changed. So your way to resolve this: get sources from svn, replace those lines and compile it. Till now this fix works fine in our project with all types that we have.

Comment: Weird -- I grabbed the source (for both protobuf-net and protobuf-net.enyim), but cannot serialize/deserialize normal `[Serializable]` classes (i.e.: without `[ProtoContract]` or `[DataContract]` attributes) with it.  It works with the nuget versions of Protobuf-net and Protobuf-net.Enyim, but not from the source I downloaded.  Stepping through the pf-n.enyim unit test, I see that my type fails to pass `TypeModel.CanSerializeContractType`.  It works with the nuget versions, not my open source build.  What am I missing?  (standard .Net 4 version of protobuf-net)

Comment: ... unless it never actually worked with the nuget versions and I didn't have enough insight into the code to realize it wasn't working.  Ah man!

Comment: In my app I've removed all stuff connected with `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract]`, because, as I think, using this cause protobuf lib to use workarounds to serialize it. I've converted all classes to use `ProtoContract`. Protobuf doesn't serialize types of serializable class members, it just serialize array of byte values and restores types depending on their order defined in `[ProtoMember(2)]`. Here those workarounds can fail. So my suggestion is to convert your classes. Also if you compile it from source you can include debug symbols and debug pf-n.enyim in VS while running your project.

Answer (score 0):

i think that memcache does not understand `ProtoContract`, try to mark them as `DataContract`

Comment: I *assume* the OP is registering a custom transcoder; if that is the case, enyim can do whatever it needs