# Unable to load type required for deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, couchbase

I am using Couchbase to store my data and manage it.

When I tried to get an entity from cache using

```
CacheClient.GetWithCas<T>(cacheKey)
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to load type X required for deserialization.  
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder.DeserializeObject(ArraySegment`1 value)
at Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder.Deserialize(CacheItem item)
at Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder.Enyim.Caching.Memcached.ITranscoder.Deserialize(CacheItem item)
at Couchbase.CouchbaseClient.PerformTryGet(String key, UInt64& cas, Object& value)
at Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient.GetWithCas[T](String key)
```

I guess it can be because of a type i changed (remove properties or changed their signatures).

Can you help me figure out how to avoid this from happening?

Comment: *I guess it can be because of a type i changed*. yep. If possible, don't use BinaryFormatter.

Comment: Hey,
I was searching for the answer and i encountered answers similar to yours.

The problem is the the CacheClient do the serialization and de-serialization .

Comment: If you're planning to change types and use binary formatter you need to provide types versioning and store all type version. This can be done in many ways. And if you're planning to use default .net DataContract serializer I can say that will be no big difference between bin and text serialization, because DataContract serializer stores too much useless information.

Comment: What do you suggest if i do not want any previous version (only the newer) but i want to avoid de-serialization exception being thrown?

Comment: Commenting as this is the top result for this.  If you're going to binary serialise and you want to change your objects, include a version number in your namespace and update it with each change.  Should the need arise you can write convertors to rescue old data with very little work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deserialize only the newest version of type you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Modify memcached transcoder and make it able to handle that exceptions (hard way)
2. Just not even try to deserialize old types (easy way)

I'll give an example of the last way. Firs you need slightly modify all your cache keys. You need to add "namespace" to it: before - `mycachekey:myparam`, after - `mychachekey:cachekeynamespace:myparam`. 
So what is "namespace"? - The "namespace" is simple counter which you need to increment after each type change. You can store it also in couchbase/memcached and use `increment` function to  change it's value. In this way you never get obsolte values from cache. Shor example about how that namespace will work:

1. Get key's namespace or create it if not exist into var `ckns`;
2. create cache key `foo` (here foo will also represent type's name)
   with param `1`: `cacheKey = 'foo' + ':' + ckns + ':' + 1`;
3. store value 'bar' with key: `foo:0:1`;
4. change type and it's namespace version;
5. try to get from cache key `foo` with param `1` (but remember that
   namespace is changed);
6. you'll get key: `foo:1:1` and as a result you'll get just chache
   miss, no exception, because it's nothing to deserialize.

And some notes:

- if you need just cache it's better to use memcached (that is included
  in couchbase installation) than couchbase.
- If you want to achive better performance on serialization and to
  reduce amoount of data that is stored in your cache look at diffrent
  serialization "engine". Good choise can be serialize to JSON (text
  serialization) or use Protobuf (binary serialization, very compact)*

*There is also memcached transocoder for protobuf serialization that can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). But to use it with custom types you'll need to apply a little fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862333/protobuf-net-memcache-provider-null-type-error-on-deserialize).